# Same CSS, different result (Bootstrap4, Chrome only)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I have images on my website with captions in the middle showing on hover. Same HTML with same CSS applied to each one. It works fine in most browsers, except for Chrome, where only the first column of images works properly and rest is broken.

[Link to my website](http://porexi.cz/porexi2017/#products)

Firefox and Edge works fine, even IE is OK

Comment: For me it looks the same in Chrome and Firefox. Maybe you need a force reload? (CTRL + Shift + R)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the transform property on your `img-caption` to `translate3d(-50%, 100%, 0)`.

EDIT:

Concerning the hover issue on the container, that is due to your `column-count` property. Changing your `.gal3` class to use flex properties instead fixes the issue.

```
.gal3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.gal3 .gal-container {
  width: 33%;
}
```

If you want to center your images too you can use the same `align-middle` class you're already using.

Comment: Thanks, this partly does it! Captions now show up correctly, but I need to hover right over the caption, while it should work anywhere on the image container. (First column works like that)

Comment: @TomášBlinkyHoněk Updated my answer to help you solve this issue as well.

Comment: Flex does fix the issue with hover, however row wrap breaks the layout. Column wrap seems like the way to go, but it won't work without known height.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this code,

<div class="img-caption">
 <div>
  <b>W filament</b>
  <p>3.08.1.100.m.o</p>
 </div>
</div> 

<style>
.img-caption {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

.img-caption {

```
position: relative;
color: white;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
margin: 10px auto;
top: 2em;
left: 0;
transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, 100%) -moz-transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
display: inline;
```

}